# Websocket connection through reverse proxy closes on first message

Tags: apache, websocket, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a Javascript client and Python server. The client establishes a websocket connection via

```
const websocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.110/socket/");
```

On a button click the client sends a message:

```
document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  websocket.send(JSON.stringify({ action: "clicked" }));
});
```

The server creates a Gateway object and starts listening on port 1602. When a message arrives, it should print the message.

```
async def start(self): 
  websocketServer = await websockets.serve(self.io, self.host, self.port) 
  await websocketServer.wait_closed() 

async def io(self, protocol, _):
  while True: 
    print('Waiting for next incoming message...') 
    message = await protocol.recv()
    print(message) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
  gateway = Gateway('gateway','192.168.1.110',1602)
  asyncio.run(gateway.start())
```

Apache maps the incoming client request to the correct port:

```
ProxyPass "/socket/" "ws://192.168.1.110:1602/"
```

On loading the webpage the connection is successfully established, as can be seen in the Python websocket logs:

```
Using selector: EpollSelector
server listening on 192.168.1.110:1602
= connection is CONNECTING
< GET / HTTP/1.1
< Host: 192.168.1.110:1602
< Pragma: no-cache
< Accept: */*
< Sec-WebSocket-Key: SjdZCnOeOcn5yXiQHfKttg==
< Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
< Accept-Language: en-CA,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
< Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
< Origin: http://192.168.1.110
< User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.0 Safari/605.1.15
< X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.1.102
< X-Forwarded-Host: 192.168.1.110
< X-Forwarded-Server: 192.168.1.110
< Upgrade: WebSocket
< Connection: Upgrade
> HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
> Upgrade: websocket
> Connection: Upgrade
> Sec-WebSocket-Accept: B0eYCJbJMf9M7aEh/JxHODlUMe0=
> Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; server_max_window_bits=12
> Date: Wed, 04 Oct 2023 20:10:48 GMT
> Server: Python/3.8 websockets/11.0.3
connection open
= connection is OPEN
Waiting for next incoming message...
```

But as soon as I click the button on the webpage the connection crashes with

```
! failing connection with code 1002
= connection is CLOSING
> CLOSE 1002 (protocol error) [2 bytes]
x half-closing TCP connection
= connection is CLOSED

connection handler failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/framing.py", line 78, in read
    opcode = frames.Opcode(head1 & 0b00001111)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 339, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 663, in __new__
    raise ve_exc
ValueError: 7 is not a valid Opcode

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 959, in transfer_data
    message = await self.read_message()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 1029, in read_message
    frame = await self.read_data_frame(max_size=self.max_size)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 1104, in read_data_frame
    frame = await self.read_frame(max_size)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 1161, in read_frame
    frame = await Frame.read(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/framing.py", line 80, in read
    raise ProtocolError("invalid opcode") from exc
websockets.exceptions.ProtocolError: invalid opcode

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/server.py", line 240, in handler
    await self.ws_handler(self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/server.py", line 1186, in _ws_handler
    return await cast(
  File "/home/ubuntu/server/gateway.py", line 92, in io
    message = await protocol.recv()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 568, in recv
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 944, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: sent 1002 (protocol error); no close frame received
connection closed
```

I suspect that the problem is in the Apache config, because circumventing the proxy by replacing

```
const websocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.110/socket/");
```

in the client with

```
const websocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.110:1602");
```

fixes the problem and everything behaves as expected. That's not a solution, though, as the deployed app would use a public-facing domain:

```
const websocket = new WebSocket("ws://mydomain.com/socket/");
```

so mapping the requests to an internal IP is strictly necessary. I followed the hints in all vaguely related questions but could not find a working solution. I also don't really know how to approach the problem, because the traceback contains only one reference to my code (`message = await protocol.recv()`) and there's not much I can do about that line.